# Prove that the maximum volume of a triangular-base prism is $\sqrt{\frac{K^3}{54}}$ where $K$ is the area of three triangles containing a vertex $A$

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

Consider a prism with triangular base. The total area of the three faces containing a particular vertex $A$ is $K$. Show that the maximum possible volume of the prism is $\sqrt{\frac{K^3}{54}}$ and find the height of this largest prism.

I have no idea how to approach the problem. Please help. I know we need to use the properties of triangles and also the AM-GM inequality somewhere, but cannot put it together to solve the problem.

Comment: Is it a prism or a pyramid? Your title seems to imply you mean pyramid - "three triangles containing a vertex A" but the post implies prism, "The total area of the three faces containing a particular vertex".

If it's a prism, then only one face is a triangle, the other two are rectangles, correct?

Comment: @BennettGardiner A prism with triangular base, isn't that a pyramid? Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: [Prism](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=triangular+prism&oq=triangular+prism&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2989j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8)...

[Pryamid](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=triangular+prism&oq=triangular+prism&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2989j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=triangular+pyramid&safe=off)

Comment: @BennettGardiner I hope the edited version is correct.

Comment: You still haven't indicated what shape you meant. Did you click on the links and look at the google images?

Comment: I agree with Bennet, the question is not very clear.

Comment: @BennettGardiner The question states prism with triangular base, so I assume, they were actually talking about a pyramind itself.

Comment: The title is mistaken.To draw more context it is a question from ISI 2007 BStat Admission test.The correct title is three faces containing a particular triangle not three triangles so it is a prism not a pyramid.

Answer (score 5):

WOLOG, consider the case $A$ is located at top of prism.

Let $A,B,C$ be the vertices of the triangle at top and $a,b,c$ be the lengths
of corresponding sides.
Let $\Delta$ be the area of triangle $\triangle_{ABC}$. Let $h$ and $V$ be the height and volume of the prism.

The given data is

$$K = \Delta + (b+c)h\quad\text{ and }\quad V = \Delta h$$

Notice $$\Delta \le \frac12 bc \le \frac18 (b+c)^2\quad\implies\quad (b+c) \ge \sqrt{8\Delta}$$
We have
$$K \ge \Delta + \sqrt{8\Delta} h
= \frac{V}{h} + \sqrt{8Vh} 
= \frac{V}{h} + \sqrt{2Vh} + \sqrt{2Vh}$$
Apply AM $\ge$ GM to rightmost expression, we get
$$K \ge 3\left(\frac{V}{h}\times \sqrt{2Vh} \times \sqrt{2Vh}\right)^{1/3}
=3(2V^2)^{1/3}$$
This is equivalent to the desired inequality 
$\displaystyle\;\sqrt{\frac{K^3}{54}} \ge V$.

Please note that this bound is tight. When $a : b : c : h = 2\sqrt{2} : 2 : 2 : 1$, triangle $\triangle_{ABC}$ is isosceles with a right angle at $A$.
Furthermore, the equality $\displaystyle\;\sqrt{\frac{K^3}{54}} = V$ is achieved.